# UILabel text doesn't update when using Combine `receive(on:)`

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a collection view, and I am attempting to use Combine to keep a UILabel up to date on a cell in the collection view. However, if I use `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` (or `RunLoop.main`) to force messages to come on the UI thread (that's my understanding) then the update doesn't happen. If I remove that line, then everything works fine, but I fear I'd run into future problems with attempts to update the label off the UI thread.

Interestingly, I have the exact same setup on another page, and it works just fine. I can't find anything different as to why this one page won't work. I'm new to Combine, so there's a good chance I'm missing a fundamental element that maybe someone can point out.

Here's the setup...

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    weak var item: MyCoreDataItem!
    
    func setData(item: MyCoreDataItem) {
        self.item = item

        self.item.publisher(for: \.myStringProperty)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) // Removing this makes it work
            .assign(to: \.text, on: myLabel)
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

On the controller, I setup a diffable data source as such...

```swift
let diffableDataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, NSManagedObjectID>(collectionView: collectionView) { [weak self] (collectionView, indexPath, objectID) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
    guard let item = try? self?.app.persistentContainer.viewContext.existingObject(with: objectID) as? MyCoreDataItem else {
        print("Managed object not available")
    }
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyViewCell
    cell.setData(item: item)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How do you update the property? Is the update occurring on a queue other than the main queue? If not then you don't need to worry about dispatching onto the main queue. Also, your current code will "leak" subscribers. You should empty `subscriptions` in `setData` before saving the new subscription.

Comment: It’s a Core Data object so the updates are going to be coming from that (ie: CloudKit sync). I’m not sure what thread those will come on, but maybe a background thread. FYI, I have `subscribers` clearing upon cell reuse I just didn’t include that code for simplicity here.